# Shell prompt returns before the child process complets via putty

Tags: c, linux, shell, putty

Please review the following code example:

```
int main() {
    pid_t childpid;
    char buf[100] = {0};

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(childpid == 0) {
      sprintf(buf,"child process id: %d\n",getpid());
      write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
    }
    else {
     sprintf(buf,"parent process id: %d\n",getpid());
     write(1,buf,strlen(buf));
     // fix here
     wait(&childpid);
    }
    return 0;
```

}

When run directly on terminal on Linux machine, the output as expected:

```
[user@192 ~]$ ./test 
parent process id: 28788
child process id: 28789
```

On another hand running the same via Putty brings:

```
parent process id: 28978
[user@192 ~]$ child process id: 28979
```

Thanks everybody for the suggestions. Adding a wait call brings prompt after child finishes.

I hope that it is a good idea to consider in a same question another case where the output differs as well, but independently of the wait() call.

This is dup() call implementation:

```
int main() {
    pid_t childpid;
    char string[] = "c\nb\na";

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
      perror("fork");
      exit(1);
    }

    if(childpid == 0) {
      close(0);      // close STDIN
      close(fd[1]);  // close write end of a pipe
      dup(*fd);   // duplicate read end of the pipe to STDIN
      execlp("sort","sort",NULL);   // run sort(1) command
    }
    else {
     close(*fd);  // close read end of a pipe
     write(fd[1],string,strlen(string));
    }
    return 0;
```

}

And again to different outputs, running program directly from the terminal,
gives:

```
[user@192 pipe]$ ./dup
a
b
c
[user@192 pipe]$
```

and via putty connection:

```
root@debian-512mb-ams2-01:~/C/inner/pipe# a  
b  
c
```

In the second example prompt never come back :(

What it can be?)

Comment: What is the problem statement here? Your wondering why putty gives different pid than running in Linux terminal? I see parent and child pid are unique. That's the expected beahviour.

Comment: I don't see any difference. Are you wondering why the prompt returns? You need to join them then.

Comment: The parent usually `wait`s for its children.

Comment: BTW, using `sizeof(buf)` is going to always write 100 chars, most of which will be `\0`s.  Using `strlen(buf)` instead will avoid that.

Comment: @JohnHascall Thank you for suggestion. Changed to the strlen().

Comment: @LethalProgrammer only the first prompt is the proper and expected behaviour

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`wait()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for the child process:

```
if(childpid == 0) {
  sprintf(buf,"child process id: %d\n",getpid());
  write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
}
else {
 sprintf(buf,"parent process id: %d\n",getpid());
 write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
 wait(childpid); // <---
}
return 0;
```

Comment: This is correct.  And the reason is that the shell prints the prompt for the next command after the initial (parent) process completes, but the child process runs independent of the parent process so you can not know if it will complete before or after the parent finishes.  Running the original program multiple times via either a direct connection or through putty will likely show both behaviors both ways. The connection method is a "red herring".

Answer (score 1):

All the child processes created inside a main process dies prematurely when the main process exit or dies. Hence before exit from the main process we need to have tell the operating system that please complete all the child processes before exit from the main process. For that you have to add `wait()` system call with a `int` value or NULL . For testing purpose you can use a `sleep()` statement as well.

```
write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
wait(NULL); // just for testing sleep(5); sleep for 5 second to complete the child process
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be related to latency in finishing processes (they are running independently). 
Putty just show you prompt after core process is finished but it is not deterministic in your case.